# In my prestashop site, when clicking 'Add to Cart' for a product, the cart doesn't update

Tags: prestashop

When I click 'Add to Cart' for a product, the cart doesn't update (unless you refresh the page). Can someone help me with this?

My site is http://ayereadytshirts.com/

Comment: Works for me. Android with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Using the debug console (check for how to open this in the browser you are using):

Could be the statement:

[17:31:03.174] ReferenceError: **freeShippingTranslation is not defined** @ http://ayereadytshirts.com/themes/theme429/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js:619

Try to set your backstore freeshippingtranslation. Not sure where that is...

Comment: In the spirit of teaching a man to fish, f12 is your friend for js fatal errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Above one is right that "freeShippingTranslation is not defined".

i think you need to set default value for freeShippingTranslation at "ajax-cart.js".

you can set it to zero default.